# Drawing a 20x20 pixel greyscale image

Tags: image, matlab

I'm currently trying to write a program that takes a user-inputted 20x20 pixel greyscale image of a digit and predicts what number the user drew.  Here is a sample image of what a typical user input would be:

[image: sample image]

How can I ask the user to draw such an image?

Comment: **MS Paint** maybe?

Comment: I wanted to let the user draw directly in Matlab.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe shell out to **ImageMagick** to create a 400x400 greyscale image:

```
convert -size 400x400 xc:gray image.bmp
```

and then start **MS Paint** (Windows) or **GIMP** (Linux/macOS) to edit the image. Then, when the user exits, resize the image to 20x20 and save as a PGM which is dead easy to read and necessarily greyscale:

```
convert image.bmp -resize 20x20 result.pgm
```